# Bitly oAuth "Resource Owner Credentials Grants" returning INVALID_LOGIN

Tags: oauth-2.0, bit.ly

I am writing PHP API for Bit.ly using oauth2 for authentication. Their docs say that in order to retrieve access token with username and password we have 2 ways of achieving that:

- [Resource Owner Credentials Grants](http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html#resource_owner_credentials)
- [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://dev.bitly.com/authentication.html#basicauth)

I was successful only with the basic authentication method, the first method does not work for some reason.

What I did was using PHP cURL methods I appended to header authorization method which was following the docs:

```
Authorization: "Basic " + base64encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
```

And I also changed content type to:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

After that I added parameters:

```
grant_type=password&username=bitlyuser&password=bitlypassword
```

And I am submiting the post request and I get:

```
INVALID_LOGIN
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means the Bitly user name is incorrect. If you are positive it's correct, can you email me at api@bitly.com with the client ID and the user name?

Sometimes the actual user name may differ from what's displayed, if you signed up via Facebook or Twitter. You can find the actual login by going to [your settings](https://bitly.com/a/settings/advanced) and clicking "Show Legacy API Key". (I'll file an issue to move that data outside the API key location.)